# Change array values based on a reference array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP variable like:

```
$genre = 'crime / thriller / mystery / adventure';
```

I use the following piece of code to convert it to an array of genres:

```
$return['movie_genre'] = array_map('trim', explode('/', $genre));
```

I also have another *reference* array, like:

```
$references = array(
    'crime' => 9896,
    'biography' => 9898,
    'western' => 9899,
    'drama' => 9901,
    'action' => 9902,
    'news' => 9903,
    'sci-fi' => 9904,
    'thriller' => 9906,
    'history' => 9907,
    'animation' => 9909,
    'comedy' => 9910,
    'musical' => 9911,
    'music' => 9912,
    'mystery' => 9913,
    'documentary' => 9914,
    'family' => 9915,
    'adventure' => 9916,
    'war' => 9917,
    'reality-tv' => 9919,
    'romance' => 9920,
    'sport' => 9921,
    'game-show' => 9922,
    'talk-show' => 9923,
    'horror' => 9924,
    'fantasy' => 9925,
    'film-noir' => 9926,
);
```

, where I'd like to lookup the textual values of the first array, and replace them with their numerical references of the *reference* array, ending up to something like this (for the above example):

```
[movie_genre] => Array
    (
        [0] => 9896
        [1] => 9906
        [2] => 9913
        [3] => 9916
    )
```

Let me be clear, I'm not looking for a *foreach* solution. That one, I can write myself. I'm looking for an **elegant** one-liner, like another array_map, or array_walk; ideally if I could combine it with the one-liner I already use to create the array itself from the initial string variable. But I can't thing of anything elegant... Any help would be much appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Some people value performance and maintainability over clever one-liners. ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just flip the array of genres and compute the intersection of the keys.  With your current code:

```
$return['movie_genre'] = array_intersect_key($references,
                             array_flip($return['movie_genre']));
```

Or combined:

```
$return['movie_genre']= array_intersect_key($references,
                            array_flip(array_map('trim', explode('/', $genre))));
```

If you really need those integer keys:

```
$return['movie_genre']= array_values(array_intersect_key($references,
                            array_flip(array_map('trim', explode('/', $genre)))));
```

Or to combine with your `array_map` to lookup the reference key from the value:

```
 $return['movie_genre'] = array_map(function($v) use($references) {
                                        return $references[trim($v)];
                                    }, explode('/', $genre));
```

And for fun with your current code; flip the reference array and grep for the genres and get the keys:

```
$return['movie_genre'] = array_keys(
                         preg_grep('/^'.implode('|', $return['movie_genre']).'$/',
                         array_flip($references)));
```

All that being said, I would probably do this:

```
foreach(array_map('trim', explode('/', $genre)) as $v) {
    $return['movie_genre'][] = $references[$v]; // or trim() here instead
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, and didn't have the clear mind or inspiration to do it myself! Thanks a TON!

Comment: Out of curiosity, which one did you use?

Comment: I used this: array_values(array_intersect_key($genres, array_flip($return['movie_genre'])))

Answer (score 2):

Utilizing `array_map` and arrow functions:

```php
$result = array_map(fn ($genre) => $references[$genre], $return['movie_genre']);
```

Note that for versions prior to 7.4, when arrow functions were introduced, you'd have to write an anonymous function:

```php
$result = array_map(function ($genre) use ($references) {
    return $references[$genre];
}, $return['movie_genre']);
```

You can easily substitute `$return['movie_genre']` with your existing one liner.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Indeed it does what I asked for, so for that it deserves a thumb up, but for some reason I tend to like the other reply more, that's why I marked it as the accepted answer for my question!